# Python tarfile extractall except files matching string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a legacy script which fetches boost libraries via a python script and extracts then builds them.

On windows, the extract step fails because the path is too long for some of the files in the boost archive. E.g.

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\<my_path>\\boost_1_57_0\\libs\\geometry\\doc\\html\\geometry\\reference\\spatial_indexes\\boost__geometry__index__rtree\\rtree_parameters_type_const____indexable_getter_const____value_equal_const____allocator_type_const___.html'
```

Is there anyway to simply make the tarfile lib `extractall`  but ignore all files with .html extension?

Alternatively, is there a way to allow paths which exceed the windows limit of 266?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all the files in the tar and extract only those that don't end with ".html"
    import os
    import tarfile

```
def custom_files(members):
    for tarinfo in members:
        if os.path.splitext(tarinfo.name)[1] != ".html":
            yield tarinfo

tar = tarfile.open("sample.tar.gz")
tar.extractall(members=custom_files(tar))
tar.close()
```

The example code and information about the modules was found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html)

Coming to overcoming the limit on size of the file names, please refer the Microsoft doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Was looking for a nicer way rather than looping over all to build a list then looping over again but this indubitably worked. Thanks